# Lvalue errors and array pointers

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, lvalue

The code goes like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int a[]={10,20,30,40,50};
 int j;
 for(j=0;j<5;j++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",*a);
  a++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Output-

> Error-:Lvalue required as increment operand

Why is Lvalue error happening here??

Comment: Because `a++` isn't allowed, and doesn't make sense anyway, so the error is proper. My crystal ball tells me someone, somewhere told you arrays and pointers in C are synonymous. If that's the case, they lied.

Comment: But how is it related with lvalue error

Comment: What does post-increment ultimately do? It stores the result  post-eval into `a`, And that is as illegal as `a = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operand of a `++` needs to be a modifiable lvalue.

From `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.4

> **The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator** shall have atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified real or pointer type, and **shall be a modifiable lvalue.**

An array name, is not a modifiable lvalue. Hence, it cannot be used as the operand of `++`.

To add, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> [...] **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified
>   type.

Comment: Sir any comments regarding Rvalues

Comment: @Arpitking well, the standard does not define rvalue. However, it can be considered equivalent to value of an expression.

Comment: The Standard does mention in a footnote: ["What is sometimes called 'rvalue' is in this International Standard described as the 'value of an expression'."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note64) I have also heard it said that any value that is not an lvalue is an rvalue.

Comment: @DavidBowling that is what I meant by saying does not "define". Also I mentioned the same "value of an expression" in my previous comment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh -- I was just pointing out that the Standard agrees with you in a non-normative footnote

Comment: @DavidBowling :) Where else do you think I got those words? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increment the name of an array. Would you have done the following, it would have been fine as you would be working with pointers:

```
int main()
{
 int a[]={10,20,30,40,50};
 int *b= a;
 int j;
 for(j=0;j<5;j++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",*b);
  b++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use to add the index value on array of pointer to display the array values.

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[]={10,20,30,40,50};
 int j;
 for(j=0;j<5;j++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",*(a+j));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]